# Sound won't play if invoked on ajax success function

Tags: javascript, ios, audio

I have a sound clip embedded in my mobile web page like so:

```
<audio id="sound">
<source src="/assets/sound/mysound.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

I call it like so:

```
$('#sound').get(0).play();
```

This works fine on chrome in both my laptop and iPhone. However, if I call this within the success function of ajax like so

```
$.ajax({
    ....
    success: function() {
      $('#sound').get(0).play();
    }
```

On the chrome browser of my laptop, it works fine. But on chrome or safari in iOS, no sound is played.

Anyone else run into this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS places some restrictions on when/how you can play audio in web apps. For example, you can't simply auto-play sounds, but they have to be initiated from a user-event (tapping a button, etc).

Check this out for more info:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-ioshtml5/#N100E8

Comment: I knew about the user-event restriction, but forgot about it. Thanks for reminding me. I'm pretty sure now that's the reason