# play sound on function success and don't overlap sounds (multiple functions)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

i want to play an alarm sound on function success,i have multiple similar scripts running

everything i try'ed either loops or plays on page load or overlaps 
since i'm using the same sound for all my scripts i need to somehow stop the one playing and play the next one from the start...i could really use some help on this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script 
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"> 
 type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
 <script>
   var audio = new Audio("audiosrc.mp3");
  $(document).ready(function(){
  sendRequest();
  function sendRequest(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "vineri.php",
    success: 
      function(data){

       $('#listposts').html(data); 

    },
    function playAudio() {

    audio.pause();
    audio.currentTime = 0;

    audio.play();
    },
    complete: function() {

   setTimeout(sendRequest, 5000); 
   }
   });
  };
   });

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="listposts"> </div>
</body>
```

as i said i have a dozen of similar scripts and div's running on the page how do i play audio.mp3 for all my scripts on complete: function without overlapping or playing on page load.
i can't use buttons,the sound needs to play while the ajax is running and stop while the script stops

Comment: Where is your Audio? If I recall, you have to stop the other audio and then start new file so they do not overlap. Or wait till one stops and then start the other.

Answer (score 0):

It could be 2 things:

1. You may have not waited for the audio to load.
2. You have not paused and reset the audio.

Here is how fix it:

```
//at the start of your script
var audio = new Audio("audiosrc.mp3");
var loadStatus = 0;
$( window ).on( "load", function() {
setTimeout(function(){loadStatus=1}, 2000);
})
function playAudio() {
   if (loadStatus === 1) {//check page wasn’t just loaded
   //make sure audio is reset
   audio.pause();
   audio.currentTime = 0;
   //play
   audio.play();
   }
}
```

Also, safari does not let you run sound when it has not been initialised by a user event. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26205767/sound-wont-play-if-invoked-on-ajax-success-function)

Comment: if i do this the sound will play as soon as the whole page  (index.html) is loaded, i need it to play only when there is data in listposts div...

Comment: I have edited my answer so the page won’t make a sound until 2 seconds after all content has loaded.